# I am trying to return users and items datas from invoice

Tags: laravel

this is my function in Invoice Controller

```
public function edit(invoice $invoice, $id)
    {
        $invoice = Invoice::with('users', 'items.products')->findOrFail($id);

        return view(compact('invoice'));
    }
```

in my View I did

```
{{ $invoice->user_id->email }}
```

Comment: forgot view name ?

Answer (score 1):

The relationship you are loading is named `users` so that is the name of the dynamic property for that relationship. `user_id` is the User's id, not the relationship.

```
{{ $invoice->users->email }}
```

This is also assuming there is always a User for the invoice.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Relationship Methods vs Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

**Side Note:**

The naming could use some work since there should only be one user for an invoice I would assume, so singular. Use plural when something can have many, singular when it has one or none. The relationship should be named `user`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong property, `$invoice->user_id` is probably is the raw integer value coming from the database. You need to call the relation like so:

```
{{ $invoice->user->email }}
```

`$invoice->user` will return the user object that is related to the `$invoice->user_id` id.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot view name to return

```php
public function edit(invoice $invoice, $id)
    {
        $invoice = Invoice::with('users', 'items.products')->findOrFail($id);

        return view('invoice.edit',compact('invoice'));
    }
```

and access with relationship name

```
{{ $invoice->users->email }}
```